# Jira: Custom Field with multiple values and autocomplete

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I would like to have a custom field in Jira that allows you to

- input multiple values
- allows you to enter arbitrary text values
- has a predefined list of "good" values which you can use for some kind of autocomplete.

The "components" field comes close to what I want.

Comment: you can try "Labels" custom field, it could fit your use case

Comment: @Elgayed Thank you. How can I set the list of predefined values?

Comment: the custom field has built in autocomplete, when you start typing it will offer you filtered suggestion list from already entered values in the system. it does not offer a way for entering a predefined list for autocomplete which does not make sense if you consider the buit-in  autocomplete

Comment: Ok, but I need to define the list of autocomplete values myself. They come from an external source.

Comment: that make sense now, if they come from external issue. I am now aware of any jira custom field that fits your autocomplete use case, you can always implement your own jira plugin to provide a custom field that fits what you want. For the Labels custom field you can input your autocomplete values intially in a dummy issue, like that they will be offered as autocomplete but together with any other values entered after that

Comment: Yes, but autocomplete probably requires JavaScript? Just inheriting the Java code from a plugin and tweaking it is probably not enough.

Answer (score 3):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-enable-autocomplete-renderer-for-multi-select-custom-field-in-jira-754978239.html is another approach, turning a select field into an autocomplete field